# What background image size will fit the page size on every monitor?

Tags: css, image, scalability, screen-resolution, stretch

I'm going to try and create an image that will be the background for my website and scale to every monitor size.

If there isn't a definite size, should I either:

- Just make it the biggest browser size out there and see if that
  works?
- Create an image and have the background hidden so parts of it are
  only revealed when it gets to be its biggest?

Comment: I'm not experienced enough to answer properly/correctly, but I'd recommend making an image that will fit nicely into 1920x1080, but still show what needs to be shown in smaller resolutions. For bigger resolutions, you could edit the image so it fades into a solid background or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try reading here [Perfect Full Page Background Image](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Comment: Thank you for the article! I've seen it before and hopefully I'll be putting it to good use. Sorry for such the huge delay in my response!

Answer (score 3):

Check out these two articles:

1. http://kimili.com/journal/flexible-scalable-background-image
2. http://beingwicked.com/development/full-scalable-background-images/

They describe a new technique I've been seeing a lot lately that scales a background image to the user's screen.

Comment: Thank you so much for the articles! I'm definitely going to be looking at these and making changes to the web page. Right now, I just made it a big background. Hopefully I'll be getting it working. Sorry for the huge delay in my response!

Answer (score 3):

There is a very simple solution to this I found.
using css3 I applied the following:

```
background-size: cover;
```